# How do I generate a running cumulative total of the numbers in a text file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a text file with 2 million lines. Each line has a positive integer. I am trying to form a frequency table kind of thing.

Input file:

```
3
4
5
8
```

Output should be:

```
3
7
12
20
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: In your text, you say, that you want a frequency *table*. Your output sample is a list. Can you please clarify this?

Comment: Indeed your output is not a frequency table

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant a cumulative frequency table. Have modified the question. Thanks.

Comment: It's not very cool but I usually just do stuff like this into a spreadsheet.

Comment: @JohnU I usually do, but the file I have has 1 million numbers.

Comment: Is 1 million numbers really a lot for a spreadsheet though?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{total += $0; $0 = total}1'
```

`$0` is the current line. So, for each line, I add it to the `total`, set the line to the new `total`, and then the trailing `1` is an awk shortcut - it prints the current line for every true condition, and `1` as a condition evaluates to true.

Comment: Please could you explain your code?

Comment: Can the word `print` be used also?

Comment: Yes, `print total}`, instead of `$0 = total}1`

Comment: Ok i get the `print` is a keyword, am I right?

Comment: what I meant was `{print += $0; $0 = print}`...

Comment: @George ah, no.

Comment: when will this overflow?

Comment: @hakermania GNU awk uses floating point arithmetic by default, so around 9,007,199,254,740,992 it will start losing accuracy. However, on Ubuntu, GNU awk is built with [arbitrary precision support](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arbitrary-Precision-Integers). So, `gawk -M '{...}'` will never *overflow*.

Comment: A shorter and perhaps more understandable way of writing the awk script would be `{print(total += $0)}`

Answer (score 9):

In a python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

f = sys.argv[1]; out = sys.argv[2]

n = 0

with open(out, "wt") as wr:
    with open(f) as read:
        for l in read:
            n = n + int(l); wr.write(str(n)+"\n")
```

#### To use

- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `add_last.py`
- Run it with the source file and targeted output file as arguments:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/add_last.py <input_file> <output_file>
  ```

#### Explanation

The code is rather readable, but in detail:

- Open output file for writing results

  ```
  with open(out, "wt") as wr:
  ```
- Open input file for reading *per line*

  ```
  with open(f) as read:
      for l in read:
  ```
- Read the lines, adding the value of the new line to the total:

  ```
  n = n + int(l)
  ```
- Write the result to the output file:

  ```
  wr.write(str(n)+"\n")
  ```

Comment: Hi @guihuy, thanks for the suggested edit. Romoving the useless import was fine of course (It was a quick answer before I had to leave, have my templates under a shortcut key and forgot to remove them), but the other edits would break the script.

Comment: [The code can be simplified](http://askubuntu.com/a/879196/3712)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian sure, there are a 1000 ways, even much shorter than both our answers. tried yours. nicely short, but significantly slower than above on a 1.3 million lines.  (`real 0m1.616s` /  `real 0m1.382s` on my system). Muru's answer is the fastest by far though (`real 0m0.709s`)

Comment: It is not about shortness or time performance (million lines is not big data). The code in your answer is not idiomatic Python. [My answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/879196/3712) is just more pythonic version of yours.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian if the more idiomatic version is slower why would anyone prefer it? There's nothing special about being "pythonic" that's just a convention that helps python devs share code and standards for readability. If the more idiomatic version is less efficient (slower) then it shouldn't be used unless you're working in an environment where standardization is more important than performance (which sounds like a horrible idea to me).

Comment: @terdon there is something to be said about premature optimisation. Readability can be important because of long-term maintainability.

Comment: @muru sure, but this is perfectly readable. It's only crime is not being "pythonic". Not to mention that we're talking about 7 lines of code, not some giant project. Sacrificing efficiency in the name of style conventions seems like the wrong approach.

Comment: @terdon I would argue that to an experienced Python developer, this is _not_ perfectly readable. When people talk about "Pythonic" they are referring to a set of coding conventions that helps experienced coders quickly understand the flow and functionality of a block of code. Every language (or more generally, every group of coders that regularly work on similar code) has its own version of this, even if it doesn't have a pithy name. Now I will grant that "Pythonic-ness" gets a little subjective near the edges, as with any coding convention, but that doesn't make it useless.

Comment: @DavidZ it is very far from useless, on the contrary, it is exceedingly useful. But when we're discussing a 7-line script that isn't shared with other developers, sacrificing efficiency in the name of conventions seems counter productive. The pep isn't supposed to be taken as gospel, it is, as you said, just a convention and shouldn't be followed blindly just for the sake of following it. That's even [pointed out](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds) in the pep8 document itself!

Comment: @terdon: I don't see how having a variable named `l` e.g., instead of `line` speeds up the code. Or how `read` that could be named `file` also somehow improves the time performance. I don't see how `n = n + x` instead of `n += x` helps in not "sacrificing efficiency" either. If the time performance is such a concern; I've added [C code](http://askubuntu.com/a/879196/3712) that is faster several times than the awk solution  on my machine.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian well no, of course not. Who ever said those improve performance? I never identified specific parts of the code. [All I said](http://askubuntu.com/questions/878948/how-do-i-generate-a-running-cumulative-total-of-the-numbers-in-a-text-file/878950#comment1368613_878950) was that **if** the idiomatic code is slower, I don't see why it would be better, that's all. I just don't believe in sacrificing efficiency for standards compliance. Happily, we can usually get both.

Answer (score 9):

Just for fun

```
$ sed 'a+p' file | dc -e0 -
3
7
12
20
```

---

This works by **a**ppending `+p` to each line of the input, and then passing the result to the `dc` calculator where

```
   +      Pops two values off the stack, adds them, and pushes the result.
          The precision of the result is determined only by the values  of
          the arguments, and is enough to be exact.
```

then

```
   p      Prints  the  value on the top of the stack, without altering the
          stack.  A newline is printed after the value.
```

The `-e0` argument pushes `0` onto the `dc` stack to initialize the sum.

Comment: Something like this might actually be the fastest over a large dataset

Comment: @DigitalTrauma on a 1.3 million lines, actually almost the slowest: `real 0m4.234s`

Comment: fun is all it needs for an upvote :D quirky is enough too :D :D

Comment: Please explain it a little.

Answer (score 8):

In Bash:

```
#! /bin/bash

file="YOUR_FILE.txt"

TOTAL=0
while IFS= read -r line
do
    TOTAL=$(( TOTAL + line ))
    echo $TOTAL
done <"$file"
```

Comment: bash is extremely slow on this: `real 0m53.116s`, almost a minute, on 1.3 million lines :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm dash is about twice as fast, busybox ash and zsh (in sh mode) 1.5 times, but of course, even dash is 5 times slower than python.

Answer (score 6):

To print partial sums of integers given on the standard input one per line:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

partial_sum = 0
for n in map(int, sys.stdin):
    partial_sum += n
    print(partial_sum)
```

[Runnable example](http://ideone.com/Sx4Uar).

If for some reason the command is too slow; you could use the C program:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  uintmax_t cumsum = 0, n = 0;
  for (int c = EOF; (c = getchar()) != EOF; ) {
    if (isdigit(c))
      n = n * 10 + (c - '0');
    else if (n) { // complete number
      cumsum += n;
      printf("%ju\n", cumsum);
      n = 0;
    }
  }
  if (n)
    printf("%ju\n", cumsum + n);
  return feof(stdin) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

To build it and run, type:

```
$ cc cumsum.c -o cumsum
$ ./cumsum < input > output
```

[Runnable example](http://ideone.com/NvIuiG).

`UINTMAX_MAX` is [`18446744073709551615`](http://ideone.com/fQmaOJ).

The C code is several times faster than the awk command on my machine for the input file generated by:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy.random
print(*numpy.random.random_integers(100, size=2000000), sep='\n')
```

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning the [`accumulate()` itertool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)

Answer (score 5):

You probably want something like this:

```
sort -n <filename> | uniq -c | awk 'BEGIN{print "Number\tFrequency"}{print $2"\t"$1}'
```

Explanation of the command:

- `sort -n <filename> | uniq -c` sorts the input and returns a frequency table
- `| awk 'BEGIN{print "Number\tFrequency"}{print $2"\t"$1}'` turns the ooutput into a nicer Format

Example:
Input File `list.txt`:

```
4
5
3
4
4
2
3
4
5
```

The command:

```
$ sort -n list.txt | uniq -c | awk 'BEGIN{print "Number\tFrequency"}{print $2"\t"$1}'
Number  Frequency
2   1
3   2
4   4
5   2
```

Comment: I like this the out put is nice :)...

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in vim. Open the file and type the following keystrokes:

```
qaqqayiwj@"<C-a>@aq@a:wq<cr>
```

Note that `<C-a>` is actually ctrl-a, and `<cr>` is *carriage return*, i.e. the enter button.

Here's how this works. First off, we want to clear out register 'a' so that it has no side-effects on the first time through. This is simply `qaq`. Then we do the following:

```
qa                  " Start recording keystrokes into register 'a'
  yiw               " Yank this current number
     j              " Move down one line. This will break the loop on the last line
      @"            " Run the number we yanked as if it was typed, and then
        <C-a>       " increment the number under the cursor *n* times
             @a     " Call macro 'a'. While recording this will do nothing
               q    " Stop recording
                @a  " Call macro 'a', which will call itself creating a loop
```

After this recursive macro is done running, we simply call `:wq<cr>` to save and quit.

Comment: +1 for breaking down the magic incantation and explaining all the parts. Far too rare round these parts.

Answer (score 5):

Perl one-liner:

```
$ perl -lne 'print $sum+=$_' input.txt                                                                
3
7
12
20
```

With 2.5 million lines of numbers, it takes about 6.6 seconds to process:

```
$ time perl -lne 'print $sum+=$_' large_input.txt > output.txt                                        
    0m06.64s real     0m05.42s user     0m00.09s system

$ wc -l large_input.txt
2500000 large_input.txt
```

Comment: `real 0m0.908s`, quite nice.

Comment: @JacobVlijm that's on a pretty small file. I added a small test with 2.5 million lines file. 6.64 seconds

Comment: I ran 1.3 million lines on an ancient system

Answer (score 3):

A simple Bash one-liner:

```bsh
x=0 ; while read n ; do x=$((x+n)) ; echo $x ; done < INPUT_FILE
```

`x` is the cumulated sum of all numbers from the current line and above.
`n` is the number in the current line.

We loop over all the lines `n` of `INPUT_FILE` and add their numeric value to our variable `x` and print that sum during each iteration.

Bash is a bit slow here though, you can expect this to run around 20-30 seconds for a file with 2 million entries, without printing the output to the console (which is even slower, independend of the method you use).

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @steeldriver's answer, but with the slightly less arcane `bc` instead:

```
sed 's/.*/a+=&;a/' input | bc
```

The nice thing about `bc` (and `dc`) is that they are arbitrary precision calculators, so will never overflow or suffer lack of precision over integers.

The `sed` expression transforms the input to:

```
a+=3;a
a+=4;a
a+=5;a
a+=8;a
```

This is then evaluated by `bc`.  The `a` bc variable is auto-initialised to 0.  Each line increments `a`, then explicitly prints it.

Comment: `real 0m5.642s` on 1.3 million lines. sed is really slow on this.